# HTML textarea appearance changed after a click inside?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, textarea, opera

My `Textarea` appearance will be changed after I clicked inside it. This will happens in `google-chrome` , `Safari`. Also it displays a scroll bar when the page gets loaded in `Opera`.

I don't want the change in the appearance.

Before clicking in `Textarea` ,

[image]

After clicking in `Textarea` ,

[image]

Also in  `opera` , Textarea looks with scroll bar,

[image]

How to disable this scroll bar in `opera` ? Its will happens in opera when the page gets loaded.

My `jsp` will be,

```
<div id="messageArea">
    <table border="0" width="95%">
        <tr>
            <td id="msgvalue" style="width:91%;border-color: #6495ED;border-style: solid;border-width: 1px;">
            <textarea id="message" onkeypress="javascript:message_onkeypress(event);" ></textarea></td>
            <td style="width:2%;"></td>
            <td style="width:7%;"><input type="submit" name="send" value="Send" id="sendButton"  /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

My `CSS` will be ,

```
#messageArea {
    padding-left: 16px;
    height: 10%;
    width: 95%;
    background-color: white;
}

#message {
    width: 99.5%;
    height: 49px;
    border: none;
    overflow: auto;
    resize: none;
}

#sendButton {
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: #5690dd;
    color: white;
}
```

Good answers will be appreciated.

Comment: You need to show us what message_onkeypress() does.

Comment: I resolved the click change and now how to remove the scroll which is appearing in `opera` ?

Comment: You want to remove a *useful* accessibility feature?  That doesn't seem like a very nice thing to do.

Comment: @cimmanon I am not eager to remove it permanently.Just when text area is empty.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to remove it using:

```
textarea:focus, input:focus{
    outline: none;
}
```

Comment: I used `{ overflow: auto; } ` already. It only happens in `Opera`

Comment: How to remove the scroll bar in opera ?

Answer (score 1):

You may write like this:

```
#message{outline:none}
```

Comment: How to remove the scroll bar in `opera` ?

Comment: Add overflow: hidden; to textarea
for example:
#message{
    outline:none;
    height: 100px;
    width: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

Comment: If I used that one means I can get the scroll bar when the content exceeds the area .

Comment: No! if you are putting overflow:hidden then it disable the scrollbar.

i am bit confuse what you are looking for? you are looking for scrollbar disable or it should be disable for opera or you want to change the scrollbar style for opera.

Comment: Actually I used the `overflow:auto` and it works except opera.opera only shows the scroll bar even if the `textarea` is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Remove border styles from your `td` element and instead apply it on your `textarea` and you should be good to go.

```
<td id="msgvalue" style="width:91%;">
   <textarea id="message" onkeypress="javascript:message_onkeypress(event);" style="border: 1px solid #6495ED"></textarea>
</td>
```

Comment: How to remove the scroll bar in opera ?

Answer (score 0):

All the versions of IE have a scroll bar on text areas even when they are empty.If you want to remove try this

```
CSS

textarea { overflow: auto; }
```

The scrollbar will return (rightfully) when the text in the textarea expands beyond it's bounds.

**EDIT :**
You can try this for opera

```
textarea {

resize: none;

}
```

Comment: I used this already in my code and this works fine in IE and not in `OPERA` . I need to make work with `opera` . Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
textarea 
{ 
    overflow: auto; 
}
```

Comment: I used this already in my code and this works fine in `IE` and not in `OPERA` . I need to make work with `opera` . Any idea ?